# Why is lolcat coloring and "writing" the new line characters with neofetch?

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a problem with `lolcat` coloring and "writing" the new line characters with `neofetch`.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.6 on Windows 10 WSL.

I use the command `neofetch | lolcat` in every one of my devices, and I've never had this problem before. But right now, I'm getting this problem, which can be seen in the following image:

[image]

Why is it doing this, and what would be the solution?

Comment: What is the output of `neofetch` alone, without piped to `lolcat`?

Comment: the output of neofetch is the normal one without the newline characters being written out.